# Automatic UV Unfold/Unwrap

Tags: 3d, uv-mapping

I tried to find library that can unfold UV for my 3D meshes, but found only complete tools. Can you suggest library?

Answer (score 1):

That a tool, but author says:

> Integration into an existing build is simple, only xatlas.cpp and xatlas.h are required. They can be found in source/xatlas

https://github.com/jpcy/xatlas